# Cordova splash screen based on phone language

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

How to include different languages splash screen in cordova applications. That is if a user is opening app in Germany then the splash screen should select a german splash screen image.

Similar to this if the user opens the app in Sweden then the splash screen plugin should select swedish image.

So my question can this be achieved in Cordova application ?

In the below screen shot I have included images with different language splash screen images. So in the run time based on the phon language the app should select a image and include in the splash screen.

[image]